# Scheduler Date Range MVVM

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

My question is very simple:

How do I get the current date range of the Kendo Scheduler?

I have checked out the example that's in the API Reference, but that one doesn't work for me.

Code:

```
function getCurrentDateRange(){      
    try{
      var view = this.view();
      console.log(view);
      return "?startdate=" + kendo.toString(view.startDate(), "yyyy-MM-dd") 
           + "&enddate=" + kendo.toString(view.endDate(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
    }        
    catch(error){ console.log("Scheduler: Could not get schedulers daterange \n Error: " + error)}
    //Default value
    return "?startdate=" + kendo.toString(new Date().addDays(-30), "yyyy-MM-dd") 
           + "&enddate=" + kendo.toString(new Date().addDays(30), "yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to reference the scheduler directly.

```
    try{
      var view = $("#schedulerViewScheduler").data("kendoScheduler").view();
      console.log(view);
      return "&startdate=" + kendo.toString(view.startDate(), "yyyy-MM-dd") 
           + "&enddate=" + kendo.toString(view.endDate(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
    }        
    catch(error){ console.log("Scheduler: Could not get schedulers daterange \n Error: " + error)}
    return "&startdate=" + kendo.toString(new Date().addDays(-30), "yyyy-MM-dd") 
           + "&enddate=" + kendo.toString(new Date().addDays(30), "yyyy-MM-dd");
```